# Search results with pagination not working

Tags: posts, pagination, search

I've got a news page with a search bar functionality. On this page I want a user to be able to enter a term and the contents of that page will be updated depending on what the user has entered. I don't have a search.php and I currently have it working on my news page. Here is my code

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>">
    <input type="text" name="search" autocomplete="off" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['search'])){print $_POST['search'];} ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="search our site">
</form>

<?php 
    $i = 0;
    global $the_query;
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

    if(isset($_REQUEST['search'])){
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => '',
            's' => $_REQUEST['search'],
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'paged' => $paged
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    } else {
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => '',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'paged' => $paged
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    }
    if ($the_query->have_posts()):
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); 
    $i++;  
    $newsFields = get_fields();
?>

<?php if ($i % 2 == 0) { ?>
<section>
    <?= the_title(); ?>
    <?= the_excerpt();?>
</section>
<?php } else { ?>

<section>
<?= the_title(); ?>
<?= the_excerpt();?>
</section>
        
<?php } ?>

<?php
endwhile; ?>
<div class="pagination">
    <?php 
        echo paginate_links( array(
            'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ) ),
            'total'        => $the_query->max_num_pages,
            'current'      => 'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'format'       => '?paged=%#%',
            'show_all'     => false,
            'type'         => 'plain',
            'end_size'     => 2,
            'mid_size'     => 1,
            'prev_next'    => true,
            'prev_text'    => sprintf( '<i></i> %1$s', __( 'Previous', 'text-domain' ) ),
            'next_text'    => sprintf( '%1$s <i></i>', __( 'Next', 'text-domain' ) ),
            'add_args'     => false,
            'add_fragment' => '',
        ) );
    ?>
</div>
```

However, I am facing an issue with my pagination. Once I enter a term and the page is updated with posts related to that term and I hit the next page this gets refreshed and all posts are retrieved again. I've Looked and read through other posts to see if I could fix it but still nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What's the reason for not using `search.php`? Have you looked into `pre_get_posts`?

Comment: Hi @TomJNowell I'm fairly new to creating custom search queries and thought that this would be possible without having to use search.php (need to give it a further read). Looking into `pre_get_posts` now

Comment: The fundamental problem here is that you ignored the main query/post loop and created a brand new query. This means you have to re-build everything from scratch, as all the APIs, the URLs, etc, all work on the main query, not this second query. If you need to change the posts the main query fetches, do that, don't create a new query